# Trying to power three separate 12 V circuits with one wall wart

Tags: power-supply, wiring

I’m quite new to all of this and I’m working on a project.  I know the wiring for one, but I’m not sure how to do three together.

Here’s my wiring diagram - right under the momentary switch is the DC power input.  Can anyone help me understand how to wire three independent circuits of these off one wall wart?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have three toggle switches and three momentary buttons? Or control three instances from one set of controls?

Comment: They are double throw double position momentary switches where the power is going too.  My problem is that I have three sewage circuits controlling three of the same, but independent things.  Each circuit has a toggle and a button though

Comment: Just so you don't get confused later, switches have "throws" and "poles" which are separate from number of positions. For example, a double pole double throw (DPDT) switch could have two or three positions (a center third position where nothing is connected). Also... *sewage* circuit?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wire the three sets in parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ1OlC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ground symbols represent the negative connection to the power supply. Connecting loads in parallel means that they all have the same voltage applied.

Comment: If I understand correctly... should I just split the red and black from the wart into 3 reds and 3 blacks and connect each one pair of those for each control circuit?

Comment: @Jeron Yes, that is right. Note the electrons don't care which colour wire it is, so if you want to save money by only having one colour of wire, you're allowed to (but you have to remember which is which)

Comment: I mocked up the best thing I could here of a wiring diagram.  Does this look anything close to right?
https://i.imgur.com/QA0DrOz.jpg

Comment: @Jeron Your diagram is correct. Good luck with the project!

Comment: You could use center-off spring-loaded toggle or paddle switches and eliminate the pushbutton. I found some interesting products for model RR controls: https://www.berretthillshop.com/using-touch-toggles-in-a-large-model-railroad-panel/